# Can't update Python from 3.6 to 3.7 in MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, updates

I have tried several commands to update python 3.6 to python 3.7 in homebrew on MacOS.

I have tried (as administrator user):

```
brew update
```

This claimed to install python 3.7

```
brew upgrade

brew link python3    

brew link --overwrite python3

brew unlink python && brew link python

brew switch python 3.7.0

brew switch python 3.7.5
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5
24 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5
```

After all those attempts, I still get this:
    python3 --version
    Python 3.6.5

Can someone please help me to get switched over to python3?

Comment: What is the output of `which python3` ? Check that it's the same as the "_Python has been installed as..._" section of `brew info python3`.

Comment: `which python3` -> `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` and `brew info python3` -> `python: stable 3.7.5 (bottled), HEAD`.  So they are not the same

Comment: 3.7 is installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7.  However, I'm not exactly sure how to change the link to that.

Comment: It seems your `python3` is not the one installed/managed by Homebrew. Did you do `brew install python3` ? Because `brew info python3` should show something like "_Python has been installed as /usr/local/bin/python3_" which should be the same as the output of `which python3`.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I installed in several years ago.  I may have downloaded it and installed it?  Can I easily change to the homebrew installation, or will I lose all my installed packages?

Comment: How did you install the original Python 3.6.5? I think it's from a Python installer for Mac, because it's in */Library/Frameworks/..*. Homebrew manages its own `python3` installation in (normally) */usr/local/*, along with all the site-packages at */usr/local/lib/python3.X/site-packages*.

Comment: I may have used the Mac installer.  Do you know how to change the installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final solution was that Python 3.7 was already installed and could be accessed using the command `python3.7`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774768/cant-update-python-from-3-6-to-3-7-in-macos?noredirect=1#comment103835779_58774768):

> `which python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`

Your `python3` is not the same one installed/managed by Homebrew.
(Maybe it's from a [Python .pkg installer for Mac](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/)?).

First, install it via Homebrew:

```
$ brew uninstall python3   # let's start from scratch
$ brew install python3
```

Check where it's installed:

```
$ brew info python3
python: stable 3.7.5 (bottled), HEAD
...
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

If you need Homebrew's Python 2.7 run
  brew install python@2

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
...
```

Notice that Homebrew installed it at */usr/local/bin/python3* and the site-packages are stored at the corresponding */usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages*.

Next, you need to make sure your OS looks for `python3` at that same path.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If you don't see */usr/local/bin* there, add it to your `PATH` by adding this to your *~/.bash_profile*:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then `source` the updated *~/.bash_profile* (or restart your Terminal).

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ echo $PATH
```

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774768/cant-update-python-from-3-6-to-3-7-in-macos?noredirect=1#comment103835779_58774768), if your `PATH` shows */Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3*, you'll either have to remove it by explicitly setting the full `PATH` in your *.bash_profile* or make sure it comes *after* Homebrew's Python in */usr/local/bin*.

Finally, check that `python3` is now correct:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 gino  admin  38 Oct  4 17:35 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3
$ python3 -V
Python3.7.5
```

Notice that `python3` should be the `python3` installed by Homebrew in the *../Cellar* directory.

> *Can I easily change to the homebrew installation, or will I lose all my installed packages?*

I would recommend re-installing the packages over at Homebrew's `python3`'s *site-packages* folder. If you maintained a *requirements.txt* file for your Python projects, it's as simple as:

```
$ python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: When i `echo $PATH` I have `usr/local/bin` but before that I also have `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:` so since they are both in the $PATH python will still look for the old version.

Comment: Although your answer did not solve the problem for me.  I was able to solve the problem based on your help so thank you.  I looked at the `.bash_profile` and found that those paths were there. I tried using `python3.7 --version` and it is able to access python 3.7.

Comment: Ahh, I don't have the Python installer for Mac anymore, so I forgot about it adding the */Library/Frameworks/...* to the `PATH`. I can't remember how I got rid of that old installation, but yeah, you need to remove it from your `PATH`.