# How to execute latest version python which just been installed?

Tags: python-3.x, version

I just installed the latest python(3.7.6).

Then I open python file as I usually do, my Mac open the file with version 3.7.3, not 3.7.6(as shown in the image)

How to open a python file with latest version of Python installed on PC?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3JOM.png)

Comment: not really, I used python(3.7.3) until this morning, but having problem with tensorflow.
Google told me I need to upgrade python to 3.7.6, so I upgrade python by brew(as the image shown), but I cannot open a python file with new version python

Comment: When I open python file as I usually do, my Mac open the file with version 3.7.3, not 3.7.6

Comment: to whom has the same problem, maybe this can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774768/cant-update-python-from-3-6-to-3-7-in-macos

Answer (score 0):

just execute the below code if your .path to py file is test.py.

```
python3 test.py
```

if you only have one python in you machine, then you can execute the below command.

```
python test.py
```

Comment: It seems that execute python3 test.py would execute in the old version(3.7.3).

Comment: can you show the error when you execute both the above commands.

Comment: ```import sys.   
print(sys.version)
```

Comment: ```python text.py 
```                   
3.7.3 (default, Dec 13 2019, 19:58:14) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]

```python3 text.py. 
```
3.7.3 (default, Dec 13 2019, 19:58:14) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]